# read questions from a file and check the answer in other file

Tags: php, file

I'm having a trouble and I can't understand why.

It's quite simple. Read from a random line from a file, show the question to the user and receive the answer. Check in other file if the answer is correct.

```php
//open the file and count the number of lines (i.e; the number of questions)
$pointer = fopen('questions.txt','r');
$num=0;
while(!feof($pointer)){
$line = fgets($pointer);
$num++;
}
//take a random question from the file
$rnd = mt_rand(0,$num-1);
$question = file('questions.txt');

$mess = '';
if(isset($_POST['text'])){

//take the number of the line and check if both answers are the same
$rnd2 = $_POST['val'];
$answer_usr = $_POST['text'];

$answr_file = file('answers.txt');
$answ = $answr_file[$rnd2];

if($answ == $answer_usr)
    {$mess = 'Correct';}
else
    {$mess = 'Try again';}
}
```

The HTML code is the following:

```
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <span><?php echo $question[$rnd] ?></span>
    <input type="hidden" name="val" value="<?php echo $rnd ?>"/>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="text"/>
        <input type="submit" value="click"/>
    </div>

    <span><?php echo $mess ?></span>
</form>
```

I've checked both answer are the same, but $mess variable always says "try again".

Anybody knows where is my error?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Use `var_dump` and check **every** variable in your script.

Comment: @zerkms You're right. Using trim function it works fine. I can guess it's because of the '\n' or something similar (not sure), but I don't understand why. I used var_dump as you suggest and I realized there're two more characters in the answer file. One of the was a space character, I don't see the other one. Do you know the reason of this? (why it puts two more characters?). Thanks

Comment: Check it with a loop and `ord()`